# ASP.NET MVC : sorting column of my webgrid executes the wrong action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am stuck on this problem: I have an ajax button to add a gridview in a page, so far it works but when I want to sort on one of the columns, it sends me to a page with the result of my gridview

[image]

[image]

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetDataGridDoc", new AjaxOptions
                                             {
                                                 HttpMethod = "GET",
                                                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                 UpdateTargetId = "ResultDataGrid",
                                             }))
{
     .........
     <div id="ResultDataGrid">
        @if (Model.DatepickerBegin != null && Model.DatepickerTo != null)
        {
            {Html.RenderAction("GetDataGridDoc");}
        }
   </div>
}
```

In my action:

```
IEnumerable<Document> test = _resultRecherche.ListeDesDocuments.ToList();

return PartialView("_ResultatRecherche", test);
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found, this is pudding Ajax paramètre in m'y webgrid...